# Loading primefaces inside a div

Tags: javascript, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm trying to load a jsf 2 page inside a div element of another page.
The problem is every time I load the jsf page inside the div, primefaces load the javascript resources that render the components and fail because the javascript are already loaded into the DOM in the previous call.

It is possible to load a jsf / facelets page inside a div?

How can I handle this issue with the javascript primefaces resources?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can't include a complete stand-alone xhtml file. But you can extract the contents to a seperate `<ui:include>` file and include this in both pages. Basic example here: [How to include another XHTML in XHTML using JSF 2.0 Facelets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792862/how-to-include-another-xhtml-in-xhtml-using-jsf-2-0-facelets)

Answer (score 0):

you can use facelets, example: `<ui:include src="yourxhtml.xhtml" />`